# Missing reponsive for website in Iphone6s and safari 5.1.7

Tags: css, html, responsive

My site have error responsive when i check in Iphone6s and Safari 5.1.7.Another browser it ok.

Link: http://www.aste.com.sg

[image: Bug here]

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail about what you are trying to do and what the error is? Also, please post the code or what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

I know why this has bug , IOS do not got properties : min-width:unset, so i changed min-width:100% , it's ok.